# how to seperate numbers from a string optimally

Tags: python, list

I'd like to remove strings in my list.

Suppose,

 **x = ['feature 1' , 'feature 2' , 'feature 3' , 'feature 4']**

I want to achieve, 
**x = [1, 2, 3, 4]**

I know this can be achieved by splitting each individual element and removing the **feature** term and retaining the remaining value. 
 **BUT** 
i want to create a common function to achieve something like this and more optimal function rather than extracting each indiviual element and doing it.. It's cumbersome. 
 
**INSTEAD**
I want a solution which auto detects the strings and removes it in each element. 
 
 **NOW THAT'S OPTIMAL** 
 Please let me know below if there's anything like it.

Comment: `re.findall("\d+",str(x))` I guess would probably do what you want

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you, but @Joran Beasley code above is more optimal i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should help you to do what you require:

```
import re
x = ['feature 1' , 'feature 2' , 'feature 3' , 'feature 4']

def remove_strings(x):
    y = [int(re.findall('\d+', i)[0]) for i in x]
    return y

remove_strings(x)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist = []
def liststringtoint(list1):
    for word in list1:
        for letter in word:
            if letter.isnumeric():
                letter = int(letter)
                newlist.append(letter)
```

Comment: Good work!
But i want the resultant list to be inline without creating new list.